# Meteor npm install font-awesome, cannot find module 'fontawesome'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, font-awesome

I am using meteor 1.4.1.1 with NPM support. I installed the npm "font-awesome" package and getting the error on the console "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'fontawesome'".  I installed it with

```
meteor npm install --save font-awesome
```

The package seems to be installed correctly, folder inside of node_modules is created.

I imported the package in client/main.js with 
`import fontawesome from 'font-awesome';`

Sadly no icons are showing up, when i `console.log(fontawesome);` i get the above mentioned error back.

Thanks in advance, mario

Comment: Do you want `font-awesome` (hyphen) or `fontawesome` (no hyphen)? Those are two different packages.

Comment: font-awesome --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome, sorry i put a spelling mistake in the import, i corrected it in the description

Answer (score 0):

There are different Font Awesome packages with almost the same name:

- [`font-awesome`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome)
- [`fontawesome`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fontawesome)

The first seems to be pretty useless for use in Node, or as a module, since it doesn't provide a `main` entry in its `package.json`.

Judging by your expectations (*"no icons are showing up"*), I think you want to install the second package (without the hyphen in the name), which shows the following for me:

```
$ node -pe 'require("fontawesome")'
{ [Function]
  glass: '�',
  music: '�',
  search: '�',
  envelopeO: '�',
  ...
```

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for your answer. Sadly it doesn´t work also. how do you import it in meteor? Br, mario

Comment: @MarioDeubler sorry, I don't have any Meteor experience (only Node).